# asp.net sending file by FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I create a CSV file using DataTable. Then, I'm trying to send it to FTP server.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

/*
    Here I create my DataTable
*/

// Convert the file to .CSV
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}

// Send the Property File (FTP)
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + "myFile.csv");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
//Enter FTP Server credentials
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length; 
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
request.EnableSsl = false;
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

However, it is returning the error: `The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."}   System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}`

I don't understand. The file won't be find because I'm creating the file, I'm not reading from the server.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does ftpFolder exist? does that variable end in a `/` so the filename concatenation works?  Does it work if you try manually an FTP client?

Comment: Yes. The url is "ftp:// myserver/beta/myFile.csv"

Comment: sorry, you were right. The ftp path was wrong. How can I set your answer as the solution?

Comment: 1) don't use DataTable. It's inefficient, slow, and a pointless abstraction. Stick to plain old strongly typed classes when possible 2) don't build up CSV content yourself. You'll get it wrong. Use a pre-existing tool that handles all the issues for you, such as [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). 3) The built in FTP API's aren't pleasant to work with. Look into alternatives such as [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP).